# Hide a section if the images inside are not present

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML code with more section like this:

```html
<section class="grid-1">

    <div class="item-2">

      <div class="item-6">
        <img src="../img/image1.png" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor" style="display: none;">
       </div>

       <div class="item-6">
        <img id="currentPhoto" src="../img/image2.png" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor" style="display: none;">
       </div>

       <div class="item-6">
        <img id="currentPhoto" src="../img/image3.png" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)" class="hover-shadow cursor" style="display: none;">
       </div>

    </div>
    
</section>
```

the style="display: none;" has been added from this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach(function(img){
    img.onerror = function(){this.style.display='none';};
   })
});
```

but is it possible to hide all the section class grid-1 if all the images sources are not available?

Comment: Sure that would be possible - you would have to count how many such images each section contains to begin with, and then for each image that fails to load, increase a second counter (also per section). And then you check if that counter has (already) reached the number of images inside that section. If so, from the current image, you navigate up to the section element, and hide it …

Answer (score 1):

You could add a class to the not loaded images (or a data-attribute if you may) and then compare they to the total images amount in the grid.

```js
function checkGrid(image) {
  const grid = image.closest('section');
  const gridImages = grid.querySelectorAll('img');
  const gridImagesWithError = grid.querySelectorAll('img.invalid-src');

  if(gridImagesWithError.length === gridImages.length) {
    grid.style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('img');

  images.forEach(function(image) {
    image.onerror = function() {
      this.classList.add('invalid-src');
      this.style.display = 'none';

      checkGrid(this);
    };
  });
});
```

Although this works, in order to check multiple grids, it is recommended that you add a class to the grids so the query selector wouldn't have to rely solely on the section tag which can be unsafe.

Comment: In this way it seems that works only for the first section, in which i have all the 3 images and so the if comparison does not work (it compares 0 === 3). why it doesn't check for the right section?

Comment: This could be improved by passing `this` to `checkGrid` as `img`, then use `const grid = img.closest('section');` Then it wouldn't depend on there being a specific section.

Comment: Oh, nice. Thanks for the hint, I'm editing the answer.